# Why the extra words "who sits on his throne", "who is behind the millstone"?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, egypt, plagues-makkos, bo

In Parshas Bo, [11:5](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%99%D7%90_%D7%94), the Torah says:

> "Every firstborn in the land of Egypt shall die, from the firstborn of Pharaoh **who sits on his throne**, to the firstborn of the slave-woman **who is behind the millstone**, and all the firstborn of the animal".

We know what kings do; they sit on thrones. We know what slaves do; menial labor.

Why does the Torah use these extra words ( in bold above)?
What do we learn out from them?

(The assumption being that the Torah is exact in every way and every word can be learned from.)

Comment: I'm just pointing out my [last comment to avi's answer](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13602/why-the-extra-words-who-sits-on-his-throne-who-is-behind-the-millstone?rq=1#comment32005_13615) here because it might be overlooked at the end of our discussion, but as far as I can tell his answer is wrong, because if מבכור פרעה היושב על כסאו refers to Par'oh himself, as avi contends, then [12:29](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%99%D7%91_%D7%9B%D7%98) would imply that Par'oh was actually killed.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/53027

Answer (score 4):

[Rashi](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9596&st=&pgnum=142) explains that from the most illustrious to the lowliest ones were afflicted.

There are different levels of slaves, and those behind the millstone were the absolute lowest level. And Pharaoh was on the absolute highest level.

Comment: How does this answer the question? Take away the words in bold above and the implication Rashi mentions (from illustrious to lowly) remains intact.

Comment: @jake, in a way it wouldn't. Having these words adds the nuance that it's not only the highest and lowest *people*, but the highest and lowest *ranks* of society. (If, for example, "Pharaoh's son" was, because of some strange circumstance, "behind the millstone" in jail, he'd still retain his personal dignity as an aristocrat, and vice versa.)

Comment: I would have thought cess pit cleaner would be the lowest of the slaves

Answer (score 4):

The first bold term is obvious. Without the words "Who sits on his throne", you would think that only Pharoh's son, and not Pharoah himself would be threatened with the plague.

Once that phrase is required, then the next phrase 'behind the millstone" is also needed.  Because if it only mentioned the throne, then you might think that only the slaves of Pharaoh's house were threatened.  Alternatively, if the Pharoah is in charge of all grain production as we were told with the story of Yoseph, then perhaps the first born of the slave woman behind the mill house is telling us that it was only the first born of the aristocrats that were threatened, but even their slaves.... Yet on the other hand, we are told that all of Egypt became slaves to pharaoh, so that might have been redundant.  Regardless, the phrase allows us to think and ponder about the heirachy of Egyptian society, and to know that the plague affected them all. Without the second phrase, we might think it was only a limited group.

Comment: But Par'oh is not par'oh's son. It seems to actually _exclude_ par'oh himself from the plague! I think sitting on the throne is to say that par'oh might have had many bechor's through different wives and this is specifying even the highest one.

Comment: @DoubleAA What do you mean Paroh is not parohs son?  The current paraoh is the son of the Paroah that knew Yosef.. or the paraoh that actually talked to yosef if you read the verse differently.  In addition, your reading makes all the questions about why Paraoh didn't die, with fancy midrashic answers non-questions.

Comment: Indeed it makes all the fancy midrashic answers not according to peshuto shel mikra. What's the problem with that?

Comment: @DoubleAA No, it makes the question not a question.

Comment: Your question is on the midrash not me. I'm saying a pshat. If it fits the text then it's fine. You should now ask why the midrash did or did not take the view and what it did with it.

Comment: No, it's not the pshat, its your drash of it.  The pshat is that it includes the current Pharoah, that is sitting on the throne.  Hence the need for the phrase!

Comment: How is it not pshat? All it uses is the text itself. You're the one using external sources to question it. If you find another read of the words that could also be a pshat, but in no way does the text contradict what I am saying.

Comment: @DoubleAA I have not idea what you are talking about regarding outside sources.  The verse says , "from the firstborn of Pharaoh who sits on his throne". Nobody sits on the Throne of Pharaoh other than Pharaoh.

Comment: It means 'who _will sit_ on the throne'; It's the current par'oh's firstborn son. This is the read of Onkelos, Targum Yonaton, and Ibn Ezra (and I see no one who explicitly disagrees). Your read is backwards: it should say Par'oh Habechor to include the current king! Why would Moshe suddenly shift back his reference frame to the previous king?

Comment: I posted my idea as an [answer](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/13633/759). Let's see what the community thinks.

Comment: If it said "Par'oh Habechor" then you wouldn't need the next few words about sitting on the throne.  " הַיֹּשֵׁב עַל-כִּסְאוֹ"  is present tense, not future tense, and those are the words we are looking at here...

Comment: To your first point, that is HodofHod's question. To your second point, I think it's pretty reasonable in context to read them to mean "he sits in line for the throne" although it would take a little more study of biblical hebrew phraseology to prove this.

Comment: What do you do with 12:29? According to you it says that Par'oh was actually killed, not just threatened.

Answer (score 2):

A twist on [Avi's answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/13615/759):

"Who sits on his throne" is to include even the highest ranking of Par'oh's many sons from his many wives (as is likely for a monarch at his time).

"Who is behind the millstone" is then needed either for parallelism or to avoid unintended inferences from the throne quip as outlined in [Avi's answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/13615/759).